# How to select all/unselect all the check boxes which are not disabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, dynamic-content

I've multiple checkbox inputs while some them are disabled. So when I click select all/unselect all the checkbox at the top, I want to apply this event for the only enabled check boxes. Also when I've all the checkboxes checked by clicking on each one, then the select all checkbox must be clicked.

**Note** : Also I've one functionality, when the enabled checkbox is clicked and followed by the save click, then that particular checkbox will be disabled.I can add a new checkbox using add new checkbox button. When a new checkbox is added the select all/unselect all checkbox must be unchecked.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ckbCheckAll" /><span>Select all</span>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" disabled="disabled" checked/> <span>Option1</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" /> <span>Option2</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" /> <span>Option3</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" /> <span>Option4</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" /> <span>Option5</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="add">
  Add check box
</button>
<button id="save">
  Save
</button>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ckbCheckAll").click(function() {
    $(".checkBoxClass").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.checkBoxClass').click(function() {
    var selected = $('.checkBoxClass').length;
    if ($('.checkBoxClass:checked:enabled').length === selected) {
      $('#ckbCheckAll').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('#ckbCheckAll').prop('checked', false);
    }
  })
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  count = 5;
  $('#save').click(function() {
    $('.checkBoxClass').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
      }
    })
  });
  $('#add').click(function() {
    count = count + 1;
    $('#myTable').append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" /> <span>Option'+count+'</span></td></tr>')
  });
})
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/63bjqd8j/)</kbd>

Comment: is the number of checkboxes variable? If not, you can add to each an `'id` and test if they are enabled and set selected=true.

Comment: @FDavidov yes,they are variable. I can add using add button.

Comment: $(".checkBoxClass").not(':disabled').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked')); you can use this.

Comment: Hummm... Then you will need to do some loop (JQuery) checking the deployed checkboxes. Still, I'd recommend you include an ID to each (a number that like "checkbox_1", "checkbox_2",...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To detect disabled check boxes you can use jquery `filter` method like this:

```
$(".checkBoxClass").filter(function(){
    return !$(this).attr('disabled');
}).prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
```

by using `filter` like this, JQuery changes checkboxes that have not disabled attribute.

and use `.prop('checked', false)` or `.attr('checked', false)` to uncheck checkboxes on add new checkbox button.

so to uncheck select all on save and add checkbox use:

```
$("#ckbCheckAll").attr('checked', false);
```

and to uncheck all enabled checkboxes on addcheckbox use:

```
$(".checkBoxClass").filter(function(){
    return !$(this).attr('disabled');
}).prop('checked', false);
```

You should also use `$(document).on("click",".checkBoxClass",function(){})` binder to let JQuery bind `click` event for dynamically added checkboxes. by doing that and add some extra jquery, select all checkbox, checked when ever all checkboxes are checked.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63bjqd8j/13/)**

Comment: Thanks.Working fine.But there are couple of issues.

Comment: when all the check boxes are checked and disabled,I want the select all to be checked and disabled. Else no use of that checkbox. Then when I add a new check box, select all must be enabled and unchecked.

Comment: Add a new check box selectall checkboxes,then press save.Now add one more checkbox, try select it,then you observe selectall checkbox is not checked

Answer (score 0):

try this, it will get only enable checkobox  and select/unselect them.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ckbCheckAll").click(function() {
    $(".checkBoxClass:enabled").prop('checked', $(this).checked);
  });
});
```

check fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/p73wW/8/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#ckbCheckAll").click(function() {
      var checked = false;
      if($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
          checked = true;
      }
      $("#myTable tbody tr").each(function() {
          if($(this).find('.checkBoxClass').attr('disabled') != 'disabled') {
              $(this).find(".checkBoxClass").prop('checked', checked);
          }
      });
});

$('.checkBoxClass').click(function() {
    var i = 1;
    var totalCheckboxes = $("#myTable tbody tr").length;
    if($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
        $("#myTable tbody tr").each(function() {
            if($(this).find('.checkBoxClass').attr('disabled') != 'disabled') {
                if($(this).find(".checkBoxClass").prop('checked') == true) {
                    i++;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    if(i==totalCheckboxes) {
        $("#ckbCheckAll").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $("#ckbCheckAll").prop('checked', false);
    }
});

count = 5;
$('#save').click(function() {
    $('.checkBoxClass').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
    $("#ckbCheckAll").prop('checked', false);
});

$('#add').click(function() {
    count = count + 1;
    $('#myTable').append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" /> <span>Option'+count+'</span></td></tr>')
});
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63bjqd8j/6/)

Comment: Select all is not working when all the checkboxes are checked

Comment: Add a new check box selectall checkboxes,then press save.Now add one more checkbox, try select it,then you observe selectall checkbox is not checked

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method. Instead of using `filter` I have used `:enabled`. Also used `on` jquery to detect new added checkbox. Hope it will help you.

```
$(document).on('click','.checkBoxClass',function() {
        var selected = $('.checkBoxClass:enabled').length;
    if ($('.checkBoxClass:checked:enabled').length === selected) {
      $('#ckbCheckAll').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('#ckbCheckAll').prop('checked', false);
    }
})
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dhananjaymane11/mLyecepL/)